# Python 3.8 websocket echo client with queue: asyncio.Queue get() does not get queue items added on the fly

Tags: python, websocket, queue, python-asyncio

I try to create a client which uses a asyncio.Queue to feed the messages I want to send to the server. Receiving data from websocket server works great. Sending data which is just generated by the producer works, too. For explaning what works and what fails, first here's my code:

```
import sys
import asyncio
import websockets


class WebSocketClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.send_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        #self.send_queue.put_nowait('test-message-1')

    async def startup(self):
        await self.connect_websocket()
        consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(
            self.consumer_handler()
        )
        producer_task = asyncio.create_task(
            self.producer_handler()
        )
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
            [consumer_task, producer_task],
            return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
        )
        for task in pending:
            task.cancel()

    async def connect_websocket(self):
        try:
            self.connection = await websockets.client.connect('ws://my-server')
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            sys.exit('error: cannot connect to backend')

    async def consumer_handler(self):
        async for message in self.connection:
            await self.consumer(message)

    async def consumer(self, message):
        self.send_queue.put_nowait(message)
        # await self.send_queue.put(message)
        print('mirrored message %s now in queue, queue size is %s' % (message, self.send_queue.qsize()))

    async def producer_handler(self):
        while True:
            message = await self.producer()
            await self.connection.send(message)

    async def producer(self):
        result = await self.send_queue.get()
        self.send_queue.task_done()
        #await asyncio.sleep(10)
        #result = 'test-message-2'
        return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wsc = WebSocketClient()
    asyncio.run(wsc.startup())
```

Connecting works great. If I send something from my server to the client, this works great too and prints the message in consumer(). But producer never gets any message I put in send_queue inside `consumer()`.

The reason why I chose send_queue.put_nowait in `consumer()` was that I wanted to prevent deadlocks. If I use the line `await self.send_queue.put(message)` line instead of `self.send_queue.put_nowait(message)` it makes no difference.

I thought, maybe the queue dos not work at all, so I filled something to the queue just at creation in `__init__()`: `self.send_queue.put_nowait("test-message-1")`. This works and is sent to my server. So the basic concept of the queue and `await queue.get()` works.

I als thought, maybe there is some issue with the producer, so let's just randomly generate messages during runtime: `result = "test-message-2"` instead of `result = await self.send_queue.get()`. This works too: every 10 seconds 'test-message-2' is sent to my server.

EDIT: This also happens if I try to add stuff from another source to the queue on the fly. I build a small asyncio socket server which pushes any message to the queue, which works great, and you can see the messages I added from the other source with `qsize()` in `consumer()`, but still no successfull `queue.get()`. So the queue itself seems to work, just not `get()`. This is btw the reason for the queue, too: I would like to send data from quite different sources.

So, this is the point where I'm stuck. My wild guess is that the queue I use in `producer()` is not the same as in `consumer()`, something which happens at threading quite easily if you use non-thread-safe queues like asyncio.Queue, but as I understood it I don't use threading at all, just coroutines. So, what else went wrong here?

Just for the context: it's a Ubuntu 20.04 python 3.8.2 inside a docker container.

Thanks,
Ernesto

Comment: Maybe I'm going to write something incorrect, because I seem to be lost in producer/consumer vs client/server. Anyway, I think you need two queues to create a bidirectional communication.

Comment: Thanks for yor hint. But until now, I just wanted to queue the things I send. Until now, I just process everything on the fly when it comes to my client.

Background to producer + consumer: the producer produces the messages which will be send, the consumer consumes the messages from my server. So they are both client: reader and writer.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records -  the solution for my problem was quite simple: I defined `send_queue` outside the event loop created by my websocket client. So it called `events.get_event_loop()` and got its own loop - which was not part of the main loop and therefore never called, therefore `await queue.get()` really never got anything back.

In normal mode, you don't see any message which is a hint to this issue. But, python documentation to the rescue: for course they mentioned it at https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html : `logging.DEBUG` gave the hints I needed to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
class WebSocketClient:
    async def startup(self):
        self.send_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        await self.connect_websocket()
```

Then the queue is defined inside the main loop.